# Can't get lower values to display clearly with wide range

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, charts

I have a bar chart and the highest value is is like 60,000 and the lowest value is like 100 or so. Because of this the smaller bars are so low, you can barely see them and it's difficult to hover over the value since it's so small. I tried setting the stepSize to a lower value but that doesn't work since the maximum is so high. Any good way to fix this:

[image]

Comment: You can't change the laws of mathematics. You'll need to reduce what you present in the chart. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823030/chart-js-compress-vertical-axis-on-barchart.

Comment: Might make sense to just show the values in labels.

Comment: Technically they are showed when you hover but they are so small its hard to put the pointer over it

Comment: If your chart contains only positive values, you may also try to display your chart in log scale over Y axis. The implementation will depend on the package you use for plotting charts.